# E4 RCP application doesn't respond at double click events

Tags: java, swt, rcp, e4

I am working at an E4 RCP application and I want to make it to respond properly when the user double clicks on a specific file type. So far the extension of the file is associated with the operating system by writing in registers and when double-clicking on it, the application is started. The problem that I am facing is that when I double click on the file, the application doesn't know how to handle the file, it starts but it doesn't load the data from the file. I will really appreciate your help if you can advice me what to do. I think that I need a listener but I don't know where.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An e4 application will not do anything about opening a file unless you write some code to make it do that.

You can inject the `IApplicationContext` to get information about the command line arguments to the program:

```
final String [] args = (String [])applicationContext.getArguments().get(IApplicationContext.APPLICATION_ARGS);
```

the arguments will include the name of the file to open.

If you want to do something like opening a `MPart` then you need to wait for the application startup complete event by subscribing to the event in the event broker:

```
eventBroker.subscribe(UIEvents.UILifeCycle.APP_STARTUP_COMPLETE, handler);
```

you would set this up in the `@PostContextCreate` create method of a life cycle class.